# Performing split on node returned by nextSibling returns TypeError undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, split, nextsibling

I am trying to grab a piece of text next to an element that I can select with its class and then perform a `split(" ")` on it, but I get a `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I think this is because it is not a string, so when I try to convert it to a string first it returns `"[object Text]"`

html:

```
<span class="status_abbr_inactive">
<figure class="planetIcon planet tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile" title="Planet"></figure>Hinata [1:28:10]</span>
```

When I perform

```
document.getElementsByClassName("planetIcon planet tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile")[0].nextSibling
```

it returns `"Hinata [1:28:10]"`, but performing split() on it does not work. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you get with that line of code is a `textNode`.

To use the text contained in the `textNode` you can use its `.textContent` property:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("planetIcon planet tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile")[0].nextSibling.textContent;

var splitted = text.split(' ');
// ["Hinata", "[1:28:10]"]
```

Comment: @RicoClark please consider marking an answer as correct, so that other people with the same problem can find it easily.

Comment: @RicoClark oh yes, I didn't remember of that limitation, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Because its an object - textNode. Try this:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("planetIcon planet tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue);
```

Comment: And a textNode is not a string. Thanks, that works perfectly.